# AngularJs list ng-click to select option transformation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I currently have an ng-repeat for a `<li></li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li value="" ng-click="setLimit(numPerPage)" ng-repeat="numPerPage in itemPerPage">{{numPerPage}}</li>
</ul>
```

and a function:

```
 $scope.setLimit = function(val) {
    $scope.numPerPage = val;
  };
```

How could I rewrite this so that I use the `<select>` and `<option>` tags instead of a list.

Comment: see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions and you can just bind whatever selected to ng-model on the select tag

Comment: what does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you create select with ng-model, currently selected value will be automatically model value, when option is changed:

```
<select ng-model="numPerPage">
  <option ng-repeat="item in itemPerPage" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>

$scope.numPerPage = ''; //Holds currently selected option
```